# Comparison using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my XML that has gone through some clean up process using XSLT.

```
<assets>
    <asset>
        <no>1</no>
        <type>image</type>
        <H>224 mm</H>
        <W>154 mm</W>
    </asset>
    <asset>
        <no>2</no>
        <type>image</type>
        <H>224 mm</H>
        <W>154 mm</W>
    </asset>
    <asset>
        <no>3</no>
        <type>image</type>
        <H>225 mm</H>
        <W>155 mm</W>
    </asset>
    <asset>
        <no>4</no>
        <type>image</type>
        <H>224 mm</H>
        <W>154 mm</W>
    </asset>
</assets>
```

Now, I have to do another process of transformation. Assume that image no. 1 is correct. I need to create an XSLT to check all images to match the size of image no.1. and if the size is different, it will be post under new nodes --> remarks. Been looking over the net for sample, but have no idea where to start. This assignment is quite advance for beginner like me. Thanks in advance.

expected output:

```
<allimagesize>
    <size>224 mm x 154 mm</size>
</allimagesize>
<remarks> 
    <message>The following image has different size</message>
        <details>
            image 3 size 225 mm x 155 mm
         </details>
 </remarks>
```

Comment: Could you post the expected result of your example input? Not sure what exactly "post under new nodes --> remarks" means.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/assets">
    <xsl:variable name="model-asset" select="asset[1]" />
    <xsl:variable name="non-conforming-assets" select="asset[not(H=$model-asset/H and W=$model-asset/W)]" />
    <root>
        <allimagesize>
            <size>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($model-asset/H, ' x ', $model-asset/W)"/>
            </size>
        </allimagesize>
        <xsl:if test="$non-conforming-assets">
            <remarks> 
                <message>The following image has different size</message>
                <xsl:for-each select="$non-conforming-assets">
                    <details>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('image ', no, ' size ', H, ' x ', W)"/>
                    </details>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </remarks>
        </xsl:if>       
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**:

1. Your output needs a root element in order to be a well-formed XML;
2. Packing multiple facts into a single node, e.g. `<details>image 3
   size 225 mm x 155 mm</details>` is not good XML practice.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works for me. I have one more question, what if I have 2 or more type of asset. How do I match it with different type of asset?

Comment: I am afraid I cannot answer this in  a sentence or two. It could be significantly more complex than the above, depending on the (currently missing) details. Either edit your question or post a new one.

Comment: And please close this one.